# Recommended way to install Kdenlive on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kdenlive

If you go to the kdenlive download page: https://kdenlive.org/en/download/

Under

> Ubuntu | LinuxMint | Elementary

It reads:

> It is recommended to download the AppImage version until the release
>   of Ubuntu 18.04.

Ubuntu 18.04 has been released. What is the best way to get it installed?

Answer (score 14):

The preferred way to install any application in Ubuntu is to use Official Ubuntu [repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com). You can use search for any package on http://packages.ubuntu.com .

There is `kdenlive` version *17.12.3-0ubuntu1* in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS repository (see [this page for details](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdenlive&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=bionic&section=all)).

To install you can run

```
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

This command will download about 200 MB of packages and will use about 450 MB disk space.

---

For 18.04 LTS there is [*MultiMedia* PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Etorik-habib/+archive/ubuntu/bionic) with `kdenlive` version *18.04.1+git201805021218~ubuntu18.04.1*. You can add this repository and install package by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:torik-habib/bionic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

If you really need a bleeding-edge version of `kdenlive` on 18.04 LTS you can choose AppImage or Flatpak (you pay with disk space):

- [AppImage](https://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/) (20.12.1c, ~0.25GB downloads)

  ```
  wget https://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/kdenlive-20.12.1c-x86_64.appimage
  chmod +x kdenlive-20.12.1c-x86_64.appimage
  ./kdenlive-20.12.1c-x86_64.appimage
  ```
- [FlatPak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.kdenlive) (21.08.2, ~0.5GB downloads)

  ```
  sudo apt install flatpak

  flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
  flatpak install --from https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.kde.kdenlive.flatpakref
  ```

---

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (and newer) you can use PPA:

- [“Kdenlive” team PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable?field.series_filter=bionic) (21.08.0, ~0.1GB downloads on non-Qt system):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install kdenlive
  ```

Comment: Ok gotya. Because if you look under debian it says: "Unfortunately users of Debian stable are still stuck with 0.9.10 which is unsupported." But I see they do have 17.12.3-0ubuntu1. thanks!

Comment: This doesn't entirely work, with regards to the `if you really need a bleeding-edge version of kdenlive`. I'm currently on 18.04lts, I've added the "bleeding edge ppa", yet, although 19.x is available, I don't get it in updates, nor can I manually even install it.

Comment: @Rexford "answered Jul 15 '18 at 18:27", so this is not my fault, but it is PPA owners decision. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @KhoPhi N0rbert forgot to add the line 'sudo apt-get update' after adding the repo. You always have to update your sources when you add a new repo.

Comment: Thanks @user303371, but `add-apt-repository` do this automatically on new Ubuntu releases ([since 0.96.24.20 as in *bionic*](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties_0.98.5/changelog)). So really it is not needed here and will double network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Ubuntu 19.10 Mate. Seems like problems with KDEnlive persist, and these are mainly due to KDE widgets and libraries not being installed. I have no desire to install the **whole** KDE on top of my nice slim system -- even though my new laptop has a good amount of power, I have found in the past that having several DEs on one system causes slow-downs and other problems. The Flatpak does work, but even with the PPA installed and a few Qt libs and widgets and themes installed experimentally, I still have a KDEnlive system that has no timeline (just a blank window where the timeline should be). Would be nice if this program could be made universally compatible with other DEs, as it is a useful tool for video editing (albeit quite idiosyncratic in many respects).

Comment: Your answer looks more as bug-report, nor really answer. I have reported [bug 1849946](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdenlive/+bug/1849946) to launchpad. I [do not see](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/448597767/kdenlive-mate-1910.png) icons on the toolbar.