# How to install libmlt++3 version bigger than 6.0.1 (for kdenlive) ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, error-handling, kdenlive

I am trying to install kdenlive through the official repository but I am getting this error telling me that **libmlt++3** and **libmlt6** are outdated. As result, I cannot install kdenlive. I found the newer version (6.6, kdenlive requires at least 6.13) but its impossible for me to install it. Can anyone help me? Using this command **sudo apt install libmlt++3** just reinstalls vesrion 6.0... What am I to do?

Edit: The software centre doesn't work neither :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use packages from the [“Kdenlive” team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable?field.series_filter=bionic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

It provides both `libmlt` and `kdenlive` packages.

**Update 2019-04-14**: installation fails before 2019-04-13. I have contacted PPA owner about the issue and today it installs normally.

Comment: Yes i know but for some reason it says that these particular packages are not going to be installed... Wait i'll get u a screenshot. Thank u for answering :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oYe4OI9

Comment: Then remove PPA with `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable` and follow [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056381/66509). I sent e-mail to PPA owner.

Comment: OK i used the app image method and it works like a charm. Thank u very much!!!

Comment: The packages from PPA are fixed, you can use them.