# apt is not finding packages from ppa

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, ppa, kdenlive

I am trying to install a newer version on my Ubuntu 18.04, but it somehow doesn't let me. The version I have installed and that is natively available from the repos is 17.12.3. I want to upgrade to 19.12.3 to open a project file from a friend. In order to do that, I added the launchpad ppa of kdenlive to my system:

```sh
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
 Enjoy latest Kdenlive release!
 More informations: https://launchpad.net/~kdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable
press Enter to continue or Ctrl-C to cancel the adding

OK:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
OK:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental InRelease                       
OK:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
OK:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mscore-ubuntu/mscore3-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
OK:5 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                               
OK:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                      
OK:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease              
OK:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
OK:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists…Done
```

But after that, I still have only the old version available:

```sh
$ apt-cache madison kdenlive
  kdenlive | 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1 | http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

What can I do ?

Comment: You say 18.04, but you have Debian experimental in there. [FrankenDebians](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian/) are nothing but trouble.

Comment: As above. And the PPA you added have no content for 18.04 anyway.

Comment: @muru the experimental suite was added by hand directly in the repo source file - I wanted to try out the newest Gtk packages.

Comment: @ChanganAuto So I have  no chance of getting kdenlive=19.12.3 installed with apt ?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you added it by hand or by command, it's all going to be a mess anyway.

Comment: @muru so removing that experimental suite would fix you think ? Well, anyways I don't need it anymore, so I'll try it !

Comment: I removed the experimental suite, but it didn't change anything - apt-cache madison still shows only the 17 version :(( ?!?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended way to install Kdenlive on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056373/recommended-way-to-install-kdenlive-on-ubuntu-18-04) . Also run `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable` to remove unnecessary PPA without packages for 18.04 (bionic).