# Install old version of Kdenlive

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, freeze, versions, kdenlive

I recently switched back to Ubuntu proper (20.04 version) from Peppermint 10. So, I installed my programs including kdenlive 20.08.3 which worked fine for about 1 month. Then started to freeze at or near the end of rendering (that is my laptop entire system would be frozen). But in addition other programs also were running slowly so I backed-up everything and re-installed Ubuntu. Now, everything is running fine except Ubuntu still freezes the system near the end of rendering.

I have an AppImage of kdenlive 17.12.0 to process png files to video because that has not functioned for several upgrades of kdenlive. That works no problem. So, I got an AppImage of kdenlive 20.08.1 and it works well, but I would like to have it installed locally so that it would make automatic back-ups in case of crashes because crashes are sure to happen.

So, I want to install kdenlive 20.08.1.

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1056381/66509 . For AppImages check https://askubuntu.com/a/1125304/66509 .

Answer (score 0):

You can download the appimage from the [official download page.](https://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/) Happy enjoy

Comment: Old images can't be found there anymore. The latest version stopped working for me and I can't roll back. (On ubuntu 20.04)